# How to include external html files and js file in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

I want to include some html files and use functions in some external js files in my Angular 6 project. 
How can I include external html file and js file in Angular 6?

Comment: I have read some solutions for similar questions for Angular 4, but I want want find a solution exactly for Angular 6.

Answer (score 4):

You can place those files under `src/assets` folder and specify the path in `angular.json`. Meaning, you can keep the files to be included under  `src/assets/html` and `src/assets/js` folders.

`angular.json` configuration like :

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "progress": false,
            "showCircularDependencies": true,
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/sitemap.xml"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/css/home-style-min.css",
              "src/assets/css/prism-min.css"
            ],
```

All the files placed there will be picked at build time.

Comment: this doesnt work, you can fully remove the "assets" and nothing changes, any idea why?