# Angular 5 fix relative path for Assets/ folder

Tags: angular, angular5, httpserver

I am  working on an Angular 5 app, I am hosting it on a Apache2.4 http server redirecting it with a proxy module on `http://localhost:7777/test/`

My first issue was when calling a service from the browser, it was using `http://localhost:7777/` as base URL, quickly resolved by removing the slash from my test service, `/service1/upload` to `service1/upload`.
So I went from `http://localhost:7777/service1/upload` to `http://localhost:7777/test/service1/upload`.

Now I am having an other unfixed issue with an `image.png` from the Assets/ folder, it keeps trying to get it from `http://localhost:7777/assets/image.png` instead of `http://localhost:7777/test/assets/image.png`

I tested the second URL, it returns my image as asked. How can I make Angular 5 to find my assets path relatively? In my case having a call on `http://localhost:7777/test/assets/image.png`

Here's how I access to the image in HTML :

```
..
<img  src='assets/stop_pic.PNG' > 
..
```

My base href in my index.html :

```
<base href="">
```

My angular-cli.json conf :

```
...    
apps": [
        {
          "root": "src",
          "outDir": "../src/main/resources/static",
          "assets": [
            "assets"
          ],
          "index": "index.html",
          "main": "main.ts",
          "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
          "test": "test.ts",
          "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
          "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
          "prefix": "app",
          "styles": [
            "styles.css"
          ],
          "scripts": [],
          "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
          "environments": {
            "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
            "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
          }
        }
      ],
    ...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got the answer, even if it is a bit stupid.. 
The browser cached my app so it didn't take in count my last modifications going from `<img  src='../../assets/stop_pic.PNG'>` to `<img  src='assets/stop_pic.PNG'>` .
removing all slashes from my images src worked !

Answer (score 1):

Set your base href in your index.html like -

```
<base href='/'>
```

Change -

```
 "assets": [
            "assets"
          ],
```

TO -

```
 "assets": [
             "src/assets"
          ],
```

Refer image in your HTML like :

```
src="/assets/images/footer-min.png"
```

Comment: Already tried, it does not work, I do not even get to my application. The browser is only able to get the index.html without all the .JS files

Comment: have you configures your resources in angular.json

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278721/how-to-include-external-html-files-and-js-file-in-angular-6/51279396#51279396

Comment: I will putting my assets folder into my src/ folder

Comment: Try to change your assest config as mentioned